# Assets and third parts libs in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, asset-pipeline

I'm using now third part libs, it's jquery plagins and there no gems for their. For instance, one from them has this structure:

```
-plugin
 |- css
  |- plugin.css
 |- js
  |-plugin.js
 |-image1.jpg
 |-image2.jpg
```

`plugin.css` file includes codes like this: `background-image: url('../metro/add.png')`

Where I must put it's plugin and how correct include it in the assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [index file technique](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) (look at 2.1.2) for dealing with asset-pipeline and plugins. Another option is to include your `plugin` directory in the asset pipeline , like this ( in your `config/application.rb`):

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "plugin")
```

After that you should :

- rename `plugin`'s directories

  - `css` to `stylesheets`;
  - `js` to `javascripts` ;
- create directory named `images` and place `.jpg` files there;